# Rails 3: Accounting quarterly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have an accounting program I am working on and it contains a table of pay stubs nested in an employee object.

I want to implement a system that would recognize my pay stub's @stub.date month and get the sum of all @stub.net_pay to whatever quarter(1st, 2nd, 3rd, or 4th) the month lands on in a given year.

I am hoping to accomplish this the rails way! Can someone point me in the right direction? I'm stumped.

Comment: Isn't the 1st quarter always jan/feb/march?

Comment: Yes. 1st = [Jan,Feb,March], 2nd = [April,May,June], etc..
I was thinking of a possible solution: If I got a :quarter field on the @stub object I could go from there. Just not too sure on how I would query each :quarter and then get the sum of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes  couple of different things (like employee_id existing), but should get you what you need. I did not do the summing in the database since you might want to inspect all the stubs for verification.

```
require "active_support"

class Stub < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.net_pay_for_quarter
    stubs = where(:employee_id => employee_id).
            where("date >= ?", Quarter.begin_of_quarter(date)).
            where("date < ?", Quarter.end_of_quarter(date))
    stubs.map(&:net_pay).sum
  end

end


class Quarter
  def self.begin_of_quarter(date)
    "2012-#{date.month}-01".to_date.beginning_of_month
  end

  def self.end_of_quarter(date)
    "2012-#{date.month}-01".to_date.end_of_month
  end

  def self.quarter_integer(date)
    (date.month / 4) + 1
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks this is the kick I needed. Appreciate the help!